# Laravel Auth::attempt after writing credentials, redirects me to login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-middleware

After typing email and password it redirects to the login page and do not proceeds further.
I have used 'Authenticated' middleware, a middleware that I customized.

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['Authenticated']], function () {

    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticationController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');

}
```

**Controller**

```
    $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        $user = User::select('id', 'email', 'password')->where('email', '=', $email)->first();

        if ($user) {
            if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Email and password do not match');
            } else {
                $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
                if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

                    return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Email does not exists');
        }

    }
```

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
    else{
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

In laravel 8 this line be implemented in the :

**$request->session()->regenerate()**

Answer (score 0):

Your login logic doesn't seem fine.

How about this:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
   return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
}else{
    return redirect()
      ->back()
      ->withInput()
      ->with('error', 'Email and password do not match');
}
```

Comment: I have updateded the controller but still does not work, in the controller above i have updated the way it is on my controller but still does not work.

Comment: Okay. Please update this `if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
   dd('Login was successful, going to dashboard');
   return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
}else{
    return redirect()
      ->back()
      ->withInput()
      ->with('error', 'Email and password do not match');
}`   , just to check if login was successful

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected your your browser any warning about Session/Cookie?

I remember having a similar issue and always looping me back to login.
Turns out that I had the wrong domain on the .env

SESSION_DOMAIN=other.domain.com

Its also worth to check the value of SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE if you are on HTTP

Comment: I saw .env file but there was no record of session domain,
i added 
` SESSION_DOMAIN=other.domain.com

  `

still does not work